# Change the appearance of the MUI Autocomplete components GroupLabels in React

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to utilize the Autocomplete component from React Material-UI in my Website and I've already managed to customize the appearance of the List-Elements to display with a dark background, as you can see in this image: [image]

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to style the group-labels of this list. In this project, I have to use class-components so I cannot use a solution that uses React-Hooks. I guess I could somehow achieve it by overriding the CSS of this Component, but I can't figure out how.
I already tried solving this by using the createMuiTheme() function and overriding the MuiListSubheader styling, but sadly this also didn't work.
In the documentation I saw that the Autocomplete component has a "groupLabel" key within the "classes" prop, but for some reason I can only enter a string into this key.

I managed to style the list items by using the "PaperComponent" Prop of the Autocomplete component, but I couldn't find a similar solution for the list subheaders.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: could you share your code ?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it by passing a PopperComponent to the Autocomplete like so :

```
<Autocomplete PopperComponent={StyledPopper}></Autocomplete>
```

This StyledPopper is defined as such with MUI v5 styled components :

```
const StyledPopper = styled(Popper)(({ theme }) => ({
  '& .MuiAutocomplete-groupLabel': {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
  },
}));
```

You can also style the paper in it with '& .MuiAutocomplete-paper'